# Page.FindControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a page that inherits a Base Page.  The aspx page includes a control that uses xslt for to transform an xml document to html markup.  Within that document I am using the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Headline">
    <h1 runat="server" id="h1" class="article-heading">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

I am trying to get the get the value of the h1 to set it to page.title, can this be done with page.findControl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT within a browser tends to be interpreted on the client-side, not the server side.  Using Page.FindControl to find the content of the H1 won't get you too far, as all that will return is the literal <xsl:value-of...> statement.

The best approach is to also open the XML document within the codebehind on the server and set the Page Title from there.

Comment: But when the page renders in the browser, I am seeing:

<h1 runat="server" id="h1">
    My Heading
</h1>

Can it not be accessed from the page where the user control is included?

Comment: The XML control is just rendering out content and spitting it out to the client.  The server doesn't see what the XSL is outputting as ASP.NET specifically- just a blob of text that happens to be HTML in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Linq to XML

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript to find h1 on clientside then set it to the document.title

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, because your `<h1>` element never gets added to control tree on the server. Even though you have `runat="server"` ASP.NET doesn't parse HTML resulting from XSLT transformation.

You would have to resort to parsing your XML to get the heading. With XPath it should be easy.